# How can I automatically mount eSATA drives when plugged in?

Tags: 11.04, mount, automount, external-hdd, automation

What can I do to make Ubuntu automatically mount an external drive when it is connected to an eSATA port?

Currently I must go to **Home Folder ▸ Go ▸ Computer** and click on the disk to mount it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions) lists all the methods available.

Note that one of them allows you to automount the drive at boot, for all users, without editing a single config file, through the 'pysdm' program.

Long story short: install pysdm, run it and click around.

Comment: On 12.10, when I try "sudo apt-get install pysdm", I get "E: Unable to locate package pysdm"

Answer (score 3):

Previously, when HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) was handling the hardware devices, you would follow the instructions found at http://vstone.eu/2009/04/hal-and-auto-mounting-external-e-sata-devices/

However, current distributions use `udev` to handle hardware devices, which means that you have to do some work (I did not find instructions for udev and eSata).

So, what needs to be done is edit `/lib/udev/rules.d/80-udisks.rules` and the section that says

```
# Set eSATA port type for known eSATA CardBus adapters - first we want to ensure
# the device is on a cardbus controller (upper PCI device) - then we check
# vid/pid (lower PCI device)
#
SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_host", ATTRS{class}=="0x060700", GOTO="ata_port_cardbus"
GOTO="ata_port_cardbus_end"
LABEL="ata_port_cardbus"
# Mass storage controller: Silicon Image, Inc. SiI 3512 [SATALink/SATARaid] Serial ATA Controller (rev 01)
#
SUBSYSTEMS=="pci", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1095", ATTRS{device}=="0x3512", ENV{UDISKS_ATA_PORT_CONNECTOR_TYPE}="ata_sata_external"
LABEL="ata_port_cardbus_end"
```

You would probably need to add your Vendor/Device IDs (similar to 0x1095, 0x3512). That is, add a single line similar to

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="pci", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1095", ATTRS{device}=="0x3512", ENV{UDISKS_ATA_PORT_CONNECTOR_TYPE}="ata_sata_external"
```

You can find your Vendor/Device ID by using the command `lspci`.